# Where do I get x86.jar,armeabi.jar armeabi-v7a.jar files?

Tags: android, android-studio, barcode

I am trying to do a QR scanner app,so that I need these jar files to be imported into my project.

Kindly help me where can I get this file.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are part of the Android SDK.

If you're building your project using Android Studio, and you've correctly downloaded and set up an Android SDK to build against, these files should be imported automatically.

Comment: ha really .Thanks @chiastic-security.I'll try it